# onChange not working in React for input box

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I have a input box where I am showing the value if there is any fetched from the database and the input text box is editable. However, this input box doesn't reflect the changes on key press.

Here is the necessary following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { minorModel } = this.props;
    this.state =
    {
        galleryModel: minorModel.galleryModel,
        selectedIndex: 0           
    }
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.minorModel.galleryModel = this.state.galleryModel;
    
}

onInputChange=(e)=>{
   this.setState({
       [e.target.name]:e.target.value
   })
    
}
{this.state.galleryModel.photos.length > 0 && 
   <PtInput type="text" label="Comment" 
         value={this.state.galleryModel.Comments[this.state.selectedIndex] === null ? 
                  "Not Available " : 
             this.state.galleryModel.Comments[this.state.selectedIndex]}
               onChange={this.onInputChange} 
           name={`${"Comment "+[this.state.selectedIndex]}`} 
               disabled={this.props.disabled}
      />     
            }
```

I probably think the problem is because I am using a data model which is passed as props in the constructor and the values in that data model is not changing so the new value is not reflected. Is that so? Any help is really appreciated to solve this issue.I also have a componentDidUpdate to reflect the changes.

Comment: I didn't get that. I am assigning the props model to a state variable in this component. And now can I do something like this for the `OnInputChange`
`this.setState({
            [this.state.galleryModel.Comments[this.state.selectedIndex]]:e.target.value })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the `value` attribute and your `onChange` handler, since they aren't relying on the same state, thus you have an uncontrolled input.

When the component mounts, you can load your data into the same state that is used to control the input.

Here is a simplified potential implementation:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      "pics": ['https://placehold.co/200x100',  'https://placehold.co/200x100'],
      "comments": [["comment 1 pic 1", "comment 2 pic 1"], ["comment 1 pic 2", "comment 2 pic 2"]],
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.pics.map((pic, i) => 
           <Picture pic={pic} comments={this.state.comments[i]} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Picture = ({ pic, comments }) => {
  return <div>
    <img src={pic} />
    {comments.map(comment => <Comment comment={comment} />)}
  </div>
}

class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: this.props.comment };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // do stuff when Comment component updates
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.value} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
      />
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, you shouldn't be updating props inside a component. They are meant to be immutable and top-down.

Comment: I will try this but there is a constraint that I guess you may have missed in the code. If you see that I am using a parameter in the `value` attribute which is `[this.state.selectedIndex]`. The input text box shows the comment for each different photos. The photos and comments are stored in two different arrays. Now I am using the `selectedIndex` variable of the state to pick each photo from the array and its related comment from another array. Now I need a way to edit each comment if the user wants to.

Comment: Edited my answer with a potential implementation. Adjust to your given data structure. Mapping over an array of items is usually the preferred solution over using something like selectedIndex in this case.

Comment: This is exactly correct and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

this.state.galleryModel.Comments[this.state.selectedIndex] is not the same state as this.state[`${"Comment "+[this.state.selectedIndex]}`]

So you are feeding the onChange value into state that you are not passing into the value prop on PtInput

to get things working properly, you need to decide which format you want to go with. You could resolve the galleryModel.Comments whenever minorModel updates to these indices `${"Comment "+[this.state.selectedIndex]}` on your state, or work within the data model you have in galleryModel.Comments.

I'd suggest you consider why you need two sources of the same information.